# Distinct function

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I need to include Power App distinct function into this cascade dropdown formula. This is not to repeat same value results.

Column name is Domain_Item

Filter('APSYS Roadmap Master', Domain_1 = Dropdown1.Selected.Result)

could anyone help?

Thanks a million

Jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With less information, it seems that you want to use filter funcation first, then use Distinct,if true, we suggest you use following syntax:

Distinct(Filter('APSYS Roadmap Master', Domain_1 = Dropdown1.Selected.Result),xxx)

Similar issue for your reference:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Distinct-values-on-a-filtered-drop-down/td-p/172598

If this is not feasible for you, please provide moren information about your issue such as scrrenshot.

Comment: Julie, thanks for your reply. What do XXX references to?

Comment: This is the column that you want to show in Distinct function, such as Distinct( CityPopulations, Country ) in Microsoft article:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-distinct

Comment: Thanks a million Julie! you are star! it worked